# How to remove a terminated thread from a running process

Tags: c, multithreading, rtos, qnx, qnx-neutrino

Sorry if the question is quite basic but I've looked up the QNX documentation, trying every function that can terminate a thread which doesn't work.

I have this test program that creates 2 thread and makes one of them (the one with the main()) run forever while the other terminates on **pthread_exit()**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void *thread(void *arg) {
  char *ret;

  if ((ret = (char*) malloc(20)) == NULL) {
    perror("malloc() error");
    exit(2);
  }
  int input;
  printf("type a num to exit\n");
  scanf("%d",&input);
  strcpy(ret, "This is a test");


  pthread_exit(ret);
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thid;
  void *ret;

  if (pthread_create(&thid, NULL, thread, NULL) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(1){

  }


  if (pthread_join(thid, &ret) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(3);
  }

  printf("thread exited with '%s'\n", ret);
}
```

Upon start-up, typing **pidin | grep** will return two threads in one process as expected. But after one thread is terminated, running **pidin | grep** again still shows two threads, with one of them having DEAD status. I know that the DEAD thread cannot be accessed anymore unless joined when they are not detached. However, I want to know if there is a way to exit one thread and completely remove it from the process, so typing **pidin | grep** on the process again will only show one thread running instead of two.

Thanks.

Comment: The parent thread has the right to retrieve the return value if it wants, and that value is part of the child thread's state.  So the child can't be cleaned up until the parent has either retrieved it with `pthread_join`, or detached the thread to advise the system that the return value won't be needed.  It's not up to the child to make that decision, so it can't unilaterally destroy itself.

Comment: So if you need the return value, then just live with the fact that the thread will survive until you join it.   And if you don't need the return value, then detach and be done with it.

Comment: If you want to join the thread more promptly, it looks like QNX provides `pthread_timedjoin`, which you could call periodically in your loop with a time in the past, so that it returns immediately if the thread has not yet exited.